# Preg_replace do not replace all matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace every link in a file with regular expression but when i try it, it replaces only the first match and continue forward without replacing the others. This is my code:

```
$allData = preg_replace( '|(.+?src=")(.+?)(".*)|is', "\\1" . $urlRoot . "/\\2\\3", $allData );
```

it has to take the **2nd** match from the **3** and place it after the `$urlRoot` and do this for every match in the file. It is working but only for the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `.*` from 3rd group:

```
$allData = preg_replace( '|(.+?src=")(.+?)(")|is', "\\1" . $urlRoot . "/\\2\\3", $allData );
```

You could aloso do:

```
$allData = preg_replace( '|\bsrc="([^"]+)|is', 'src="' . $urlRoot . "/$1", $allData );
```

Comment: Yes, the second one worked :) Thank you. By the way, the 1st answer you gave me when I started the program it crashes but the second one worked perfectly.